# Networking setup under Xen 4.1

Tags: centos, xen

Looks like Xen 4.1 went through some major changes as far as networking goes. With that said, I have two NICs on the host. eth0 and eth1. I want dom0 to be accessible via eth0 and only eth0. I want eth1 for ALL virtual machine traffic.

I went through the configuration and setup the bridge via /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg- per the wiki.

I have it working where I'm able to log into the dom0 and created a VM. However, my VM doesn't go over eth1. Looks like it attached itself to the default bridge that was automatically created during initial setup (virbr0).

Comment: nope, not Citrix just the original Xen.

Comment: ok - I deleted my comment. It's alway helpful to know which linux distro is in use (CentOS in your case - BTW which version?).

Answer (score 1):

What distribution is this?

In your Xen domu configuration files, you can define the bridge they should attach to in the vif setting:

```
vif=[ 'mac=00:16:3e:11:11:26,bridge=br0,model=rtl8139', ]
```

Change br0 to which ever bridge you want to connect them to.

Comment: Running Centos, i finally got it working, I had to delete the default bridge. I dont think there's a domu config file in 4.1.